# $W_1,W_2$ are subspaces of $n$-dimensional $K$-vectorspace $V$ with $\dim W_1=\dim W_2=n-1$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How do I show the following statements?

1. Show that there is a $v\in V$ but $v\notin W_1$ and $v\notin W_2$.
2. There exists a subspace $U\subseteq V$ with
   $$
   V=U\oplus W_1=U \oplus W_2
   $$
   I know how to show that for a vector $W$ there exists $W′$ such that $W⊕W′=V$ by extending the basis of $W$ to a basis of $V$ and than use all the new vectors as a basis for $W′.$ Than $W$ and $W′$ are independent and because of the dimension formula $W+W′=V.$ But I am not sure how to prove this for $W_2.$ I was thinking about using a different basis for $W_2$ but by doing that I can't be sure that both basis are independent.

Comment: Please provide some additional details on the question, and what you have already tried to do to solve it. You will find that if you provide more context, your questions will be well-received.

Comment: @JohnnyLemmon Hi I know how to show that for a vector $W$ there exists $W'$ such that $W\oplus W'=V$ by extending the basis of $W$ to a basis of $V$ and than use all the new vectors as a basis for $W'$. Than $W$ and $W'$ are independent and because of the dimension formula $W+W'=V$. But I am not sure how to prove this for $W_2$. I was thinking about using a different basis for $W_2$ but by doing that I can't be sure that both basis are independent

Comment: 2 is equivalent to 1, and 1 is obvious when $W_1=W_2.$ When $W_1\ne W_2,$ begin with a basis of the $n-2$-dimensional subspace $W_1\cap W_2,$ and extend it by some vector $v_1$ to a basis of $W_1$ and by some vector $v_2$ to a basis of $W_2.$ Then, $v:=v_1+v_2$ will do the job.